# In spectral geometry, what are direct and inverse problems?

Tags: spectral-theory, inverse-problems

I've seen in an article, but they don't explain what is that exactly. In spectral geometry, what is a direct and inverse problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is answered by [the Wikipedia page for spectral geometry.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_geometry) I'll quote the bare minimum here; more detail is given at the linked page.

> Inverse problems seek to identify features of the geometry from information about the eigenvalues of the Laplacian.
>
> ...
>
> Direct problems attempt to infer the behaviour of the eigenvalues of a Riemannian manifold from knowledge of the geometry.